# table overflowing parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In the main content area of [this page](http://festivals.ie/festival/list?types=HEADLINE&types=MUSIC&types=COMEDY&types=SPORT&types=ARTS&types=FILM&types=FOOD_AND_DRINK&types=OTHER&location=EUROPE), I'm using the responsive grid provided by Bootstrap. I want the table to occupy a column than takes up 75% of the page width and the filter to occupy the remaining 25%, so I've marked it up like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span9" id="table-container">
        <!-- table markup goes here -->
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <!-- filter markup goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason the table is horizontally overflowing it's parent element (with ID `table-container`) and extending into the column that shows the filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table-layout:fixed` will fix the problem, but you will need to set your columns' width, which might prove troublesome in a responsive context.

Comment: I thought i had the same problem but `table-layout:fixed` did not fix it for me. For anybody who happens to land here, it may help to make sure you're using a `table-container`and not just a `container`